# In Android, is Task == Application?

Tags: android, terminology, task

The terms "task" and "application" are both part of the new Android terminology I am learning. In the [Activities and Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask) section in the Dev Guide, the following sentence caught my attention:

> The user presses the HOME key, goes to
>   the application launcher, and selects
>   a new application **(actually, a new
>   task)**.

Which raised the question: Is "task" a synonym for "application" in the Android world?

If not, what are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Task**

A task is the sequence of activities the user follows to accomplish an objective, regardless of which applications the activities belong to.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html (see the 'Task' section)

**Application**

A program that performs actions.

Comment: thanks and +1. From reading the link, I understand that the main difference is that a task does not necessarily constitute a single application. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. For example a task could be: Open a shopping app. Select 'scan by barcode'. It will then open a barcode scanning app (where you would scan in the barcode). Then it would return you to the shopping app and find the best price for the item.